# SSL issues after upgrading to Spring Boot 3 and JDK21 when using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, ssl, tomcat, truststore

**After upgrading from JDK 11 to 21 and Spring Boot 2 to Spring Boot 3.2.2** the service cannot contact another service using **Spring's RestTemplate** and fails with

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://our-network/api/of-the-other-service": PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.createResourceAccessException(RestTemplate.java:905) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:885) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:781) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:529) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at com.company.WebhookService.notifyFailsafe(WebhookService.java:97) ~[main/:na]
    at com.company.WebhookService.lambda$notifySync$0(WebhookService.java:46) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at com.company.WebhookService.notifySync(WebhookService.java:46) ~[main/:na]
    at com.company.WebhookService.notify(WebhookService.java:38) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:765) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385) ~[spring-tx-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:765) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:113) ~[spring-aop-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:378) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:316) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:647) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:467) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:363) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:393) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:476) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:447) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:201) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1506) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1421) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:586) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:187) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:141) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleClientHttpRequest.java:79) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractStreamingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractStreamingClientHttpRequest.java:70) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at com.company.commons.HeaderRequestInterceptor.intercept(HeaderRequestInterceptor.java:33) ~[commons-1.2.6.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:87) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:71) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:879) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:388) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:271) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:256) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:230) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:631) ~[na:na]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:148) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:129) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:383) ~[na:na]
    ... 52 common frames omitted
```

**The certificate is installed on the machines I'm testing it and it perfectly worked with JDK 11.**

My impression was, that **Java uses the system's certificates by default** and I haven't read anything opposing that for later JDKs.

However, I attempted to generate a custom **.pkcs12 truststore** (tried it also with .jks) with our certificate, using this script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Remote server details
REMOTE_HOST="our-cert-server"
REMOTE_PORT="636"

# Output filenames
SERVER_CERT_PEM="server_cert.pem"
SERVER_CERT_DER="server_cert.der"
TRUSTSTORE_P12="truststore.p12"

# Check if the truststore file already exists and remove it if so
if [ -f "${TRUSTSTORE_P12}" ]; then
    rm "${TRUSTSTORE_P12}"
    echo "Previous truststore removed."
fi

# Step 1: Retrieve server certificate
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect "${REMOTE_HOST}:${REMOTE_PORT}" </dev/null > "${SERVER_CERT_PEM}"

# Step 2: Convert server certificate to DER format
openssl x509 -in "${SERVER_CERT_PEM}" -outform der -out "${SERVER_CERT_DER}"

# Step 3: Combine server certificate into PKCS12 truststore
openssl pkcs12 -export -out "${TRUSTSTORE_P12}" -in "${SERVER_CERT_DER}" -nokeys -name "${REMOTE_HOST}"

echo "Truststore generated: ${TRUSTSTORE_P12}"
```

dropped that into the **resources** directory and added

```
server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:truststore.p12
server.ssl.trust-store-password=some-password
```

And this however produces the following error to me

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/.keystore (No such file or directory)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:213) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:152) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:84) ~[na:na]
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:180) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.CatalinaBaseConfigurationSource.getResource(CatalinaBaseConfigurationSource.java:118) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getStore(SSLUtilBase.java:210) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate.getCertificateKeystore(SSLHostConfigCertificate.java:237) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:308) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:268) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:104) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.18.jar!/:na]
... 30 common frames omitted
```

### Questions

1. Why is the system's certificate not used anymore with the newer JDK by default?
2. Why is using a truststore causing a keystore exception?

thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Jdk 11 has a built-in certificate directory, is there your missing certificate? The certificate-path might not have a root-ca signed. What endpoint was upgraded, the requestee-endpoint or the recipient-endpoint?

Comment: You can join https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256959